# Bootstrap Carousel does not work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, .net-core, carousel

I try to create bootstrap carousel in my ASP NET Core MVC Web Application. Other Bootstrap components seem to work just fine, it's the carousel that does not work.

Here is the code for carousel I put in CSHTML file:

```
<div id="companyPhotosCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-top:-15px">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="~/Content/companies/photo_1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="~/Content/companies/photo_2.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="~/Content/companies/photo_3.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#companyPhotosCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#companyPhotosCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[Photos are displayed on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Femx9.jpg)

Comment: Bootstrap runs entirely on the server. What you posted doesn't contain any ASP.NET code either, just HTML. Most likely, a CSS file or style is missing

Comment: BTW *which* ASP.NET MVC version are you using, and which Bootstrap version? The non-Core templates came with Bootstrap 3. ASP.NET Core comes with Bootstrap 4.

Comment: In any case, just copy a carousel example from the Bootstrap docs and get it to work. Once you do that, modify it to display your own data. Break the problem into parts and solve these one by one. You can't display your custom data until you get the basic carousel to work, so that's where you need to start

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools, especially the Console and Network tab to check for problems, eg Javascript errors or attempts to load CSS/js files using the wrong path

Comment: I use Bootstrap v4.3.1 and jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it will be helpful if you could tell which Bootstrap Version you are using but I hope this will help.

Meanwhile, try checking the jQuery and bootstrap version being used. And the order by which U arrange them.

Make sure you jQuery comes before the bootstrap script.

For Bootstrap 4 Here is a starter template.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is a carousel template

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I use Bootstrap v4.3.1 and jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1.

Comment: Could U use the browser developer console to see if any error is coming up?

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was my stupid mistake. My code works fine with Bootstrap 3, but not with Bootstrap 4. Template you provided works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Robotnik. You are welcome! Glad I could help. Regards.